# NSIndexPath:indexPathForRow:inSection failing to initialize correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, initialization, nsindexpath

I have the following selector being called:

```
- (void)loadItemView:(LoLoanedItemDoc *)itemDoc
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    UITableViewCell *imageViewCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    ((UIImageView *)[imageViewCell viewWithTag:111]).image = [self.itemDoc fullImage];
    // rest of code
```

Initially, I noticed that `imageViewCell` wasn't having its image set correctly. Then I noticed that imageViewCell was receiving a nil value. Then I noticed indexPath wasn't being initialized correctly, and that's where I am right now. When I set a breakpoint on this line:

```
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
```

and inspect the value, it shows `NULL` with a length of 0. By all accounts, I'm initializing this value correctly, so what am I missing?

Comment: When do you call this method? Is it after the user selects a cell or another point in time?

Comment: This method is called in viewDidLoad. It's attempting to backfill cells in a static UITableViewController.

Comment: How are you inspecting its value? Are you using a breakpoint on the next line (`UITableViewCell *imageViewCell = ...`)?

Comment: I step through the code, starting with the line in question, and checking for the value after the line in question.

Comment: Do you find the solution of this?

Answer (score 0):

The first line (`NSIndexPath *indexPath = ...`) is not a problem. It will always return a valid indexPath. If you are inspecting it like you described, you should first 'Step Over' once, and then inspect the value for `indexPath`.

The second line will return `nil` if your tableview hasn't been loaded (yet). (Where/when is it's datasource set?)

One other thing is: Your method is currently not using it's parameter `itemDoc`, but a class property `self.itemDoc`.

It's also probably better to do this in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` (and not in `viewDidLoad`), so you don't have to create an indexPath and retrieving a cell, just check the indexPath.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Your current code

    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0) {
        ((UIImageView *)[imageViewCell viewWithTag:111]).image = [self.itemDoc fullImage];
    }

    return imageViewCell;
}
```

If you prefer you can put it in a method (like you do now) which you call from `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: Would this work with my table view, which is instantiated from the storyboard as a static tableview?

Comment: It basically doesn't matter where your tableview is instantiated. It's more important to update cell contents from **inside** the `UITableViewDataSource` methods. That's why i moved your code from `viewDidLoad` to `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: Ended up getting this working, but not using this solution. Answer forthcoming.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I build the project as release. Check if you have debug selected for build configuration in the scheme.